# Eclipse could not find the main class , program will exit

Tags: java, eclipse

I get the following error when I try to run my main method:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hsv/generics/PrintArrays
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hsv.generics.PrintArrays
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Exception in thread "main"
```

Why is this happening, I think it may be to do with CLASSPATH evironment variable but I dont know what to change it to.

Comment: Well, do you have a `PrintArrays` class in package `com.hsv.generics` in your class path?

Comment: yes in eclipse I have a class PrintArrays in package com.hsv.generics

Comment: yes, but is it in the class path of your project when you run the `main` method of your main class?

Comment: how do you check that?

Comment: Check the java build path in your project properties - either source or libraries according to your project.

Comment: Im not sure what im looking for but I cant see PrintArrays there.